# take 2 dimensional values of rows and columns of google sheet in a object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hi I am trying to take values of 1st and 2nd row then add them to a object although I have coded it like below

```
function getTime(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var d = {}
  var quantity = ss.getRange(2,4,2,24).getDisplayValues();
  var fruit = ss.getRange(3,4,3,24).getValues();
  var quantity = quantity[0].filter(item => item);
  var fruit = fruit[0].filter(item => item);

 for (let i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < fruit.length; i++){
      d[quantity[i]] = fruit[j]
    }
  }
```

But I do not like this approach (secondly, this **for** loop stuck) so I want to make more automated so for less errors in data

what I need is an object like this

```
{
    "Apple": 23,
    "Banana" 25,
    "Apple": 30,
    "Grapes": "No value",
    "Apple": 31
}
```

Is it possible to code it somewhat like below approach

```
dic = {}

for quantity,fruit in zip(ss.getRange(2,4,2,24).getDisplayValues(), ss.getRange(3,4,3,24).getValues()):
    dic[fruit] = key
```

the above approach is in python but for app script I need converted it into javascript.

[Sheet image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V0Ic.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Python code I assume you're struggling to make this:

```js
var d = {};
var fruit    = ["Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Grapes", "Apple"];
var quantity = [23, 25, 30, "No value", 31];

fruit.forEach((f,q) => d[f] = quantity[q]); // <-- the JS magic is here

console.log(d);
```

**Update**

If you need to sum all existed keys (fruits) here is the way:

```js
var d = {};
var fruit = ["Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Grapes", "Apple"];
var quantity = [23, 25, 30, "No value", 31];

fruit.forEach((f,q) => d[f] = d[f] ? d[f] + quantity[q] : quantity[q]);

console.log(d)
```

Which in direct translation to Python will look about like this:

```
d = {}
fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Grapes", "Apple"]
quantity = [23, 25, 30, "No value", 31]

for f,q in zip(fruits,quantity):
    try: d[f] += q
    except: d[f] = q

print(d) # output: {'Apple': 84, 'Banana': 25, 'Grapes': 'No value'}
```

And probably you need to handle somehow the 'No value' values. They can be a source of errors in this simply implementation.

---

Just in case. Here's one of the ways to handle 'No value' values:

```js
var s = ['No value', 'No value25', 25, '10', ''];

const get_num = s => s = (s == 'No value') ? s : +s.toString().replace(/\D+/g,'');

console.log(s.map(x => get_num(x))); // output: [ 'No value', 25, 25, 10, 0 ]
```

Comment: Thank @Yuri yes this was quite better but the problem with this is as I run the code it is not adding duplicate values instead it replace the *key* with new *value*

Comment: Of course. It's just like your Python code does. If you need to sum values for same keys there should be another approach.

Comment: no @Yuri I am sorry I missed in my python code... by adding I meant to push keys to object even if they are duplicate but I guess that is not possible else I will have to make an array of *values* itself then assign the *key*.. Well thanks a lot @Yuri `forEach` was a good approach you answered